# Is it possible to access a C++ 2D int array using a 1D index?

Tags: c++, arrays

As per title, I'm looking for a way to access a 2D int array using a single precomputed index.

In other words, I'd like to do `array[z]` instead of `array[x][y]`, with 'array' remaining an `int[][]`

Is there a way of casting the array to a 1D array without any overhead?

I would like to avoid using pointers (at least in the sense `*(&array[0][0] + index)`), since this is performance critical and in all my testing they are slower. *(EDIT: This was with a particular set of optimisation flags on an old MSVC compiler - generally not the case.)* I would also like to avoid any arithmetic or function calls, unless they're lighter than just accessing the array in 2D format.

Comment: Sure, as long as you know how many columns there are. In fact, some systems store their 2d matrices as 1d arrays.

Comment: *"I would like to avoid using pointers (at least in the sense *(&array[0][0] + index)), since this is performance critical"* Can you please explain how using pointers decreases performance?

Comment: There are many things described as 2D int arrays in C++.  Do you mean you have an `int array[maxX][maxY];`?  And as m0skit0 implies, pointers will be as fast or faster than accessing by index.  Don't prematurely optimize, you'll make your program slow.

Comment: C++ does not allow typecasting of 2D array into 1D array and vice versa (as far as I know). In C, typecheck is not that strict so no problem

Comment: "in all my testing they are slower" stop doing your testing with unoptimized builds.

Comment: @m0skit0 : I'm seeing a performance drop of up to 50% by using pointers. I don't know if this is just msvc++ doing something weird. This is with all optimisations enabled

Comment: @LukeForeman `*(array + idx)` is one *fewer* operation than `array[x][y]` (because there's no need to multiply x by a constant). There should be no overhead to "using pointers".

Comment: (and yes, `&array[0][0]` is better written `array` IMO.)

Comment: I'm surprised myself, but incrementing a pointer and using that to iterate the array does seem to be quite a bit slower than using the indices directly from the for loops

Comment: I'll have to experiment further for sure

Comment: @hobbs though their types are different, `&array[0][0]` is `int*` and `array` is `int**`

Comment: @hobbs or if to be precise, `int[<column_size>]*` rather than `int**`

Comment: To my uneducated eye the assembly the microsoft compiler is generating seems to be better optimised (and regardless is faster when run) when explicitly accessing the array with both indices on every use, compared to: storing its value, storing the current pointer, incrementing a pointer, looping using just a pointer, computing the index using y*width+x or adding the desired index to the start pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `(&arr[0][0])[i * width + j]`??

Is there a reason you don't want to use pointer syntax anyway? It isn't slower than indices.. Or even just use a 1D array instead and treat it as a 2D array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int arr[5][5];
    int n = 0;
    std::generate(&arr[0][0], &arr[4][5], [&] {return ++n;});

    int* a = &arr[0][0];
    std::for_each(&a[0], &a[25], [&](int i){std::cout<<i<<" ";});

    /*int* a = &arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            std::cout<<a[i * 5 + j]<<" ";*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, `(&arr[0][0])[z]` is the syntax I was looking for. It seems this is the only method that doesn't require extra instructions in visual c++ 2012 default release mode. The assembly is identical to using a 1d array.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's a way:

```
array[i*n + j]
```

with i being the row index, j the column index and n the length of a row.
Of course the array must be declared in a proper way before that, for example:

```
std::vector<int> array(rows*cols);
```

Edit:

Seems as I got the question wrong, sry.
I'm not aware of any way to handle an int[][] by using just one [].
Perhaps with some strange methods... I would still prefer to use an 1d array in the first place, I don't see any disadvantages.

Comment: The question is about accessing a 2-dimensional array. `std::vector` is1-dimensional.

Comment: @Eulelie user doesn't want to prepare a 1-D array out of 2-D array. he wants to treat already prepared 2-D as 1-D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a straightforward way to do it. Firstly, make sure you understand

[how does C++ store multidimensional arrays in the memory](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html)

and then use some index manipulation.